# Interlaced loop to compare conditions and sum matches

Tags: excel, vba, compare, conditional-statements, offset

I want to compare the content of two ranges in a worksheet to two strings on another worksheet. In the case of both conditions are met, the cell next to it has to be summes up with all prior matches.

The code that works fine with comparing it to one criteria:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim FB As String
FB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("B3").Value
Dim MyRangeA As Range
Dim A As Range


Dim MyTotal As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

MyTotal = 0
LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Set MyRangeA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("F3:F" & LastRow)

For Each A In MyRangeA
    If A.Value = FB Then
        MyTotal = MyTotal + A.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("K3") = MyTotal
Next
End Sub
```

However, I just cannot figure out how to insert another criteria to my range. This is my current try that doesn't work:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim FB As String
Dim MTH As String

FB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("B3").Value
MTH = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Form").Range("B5").Value

Dim MyRangeA As Range
Dim A As Range
Dim MyRangeB As Range
Dim B As Range

Dim MyTotal As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

MyTotal = 0
LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Set MyRangeA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("F3:F" & LastRow)
Set MyRangeB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("D3:D" & LastRow)
For Each A In MyRangeA
    For Each B In MyRangeB
    If B.Value = MTH Then
        MyTotal = MyTotal + A.Offset(, 1).Value
    End If
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Downloads").Range("L3") = MyTotal
Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone help my out with this one?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use SUMIFS?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, VBA-scribt above is just part of a much larger code...:/

Comment: @user2737587  You could still use it in VBA.  Something like: MyTotal = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(MyRangeA.Offset(, 1), MyRangeA, FB, MyRangeB, MTH)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charles Williams wrote you could use SUMIFS.  You can use it within your VBA routine if you are happy with case insensitive matching:

```
MyTotal = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(MyRangeA.Offset(, 1), MyRangeA, FB, MyRangeB, MTH)
```

Or, if that is problematic, you could loop testing  each item.  However, depending on the size of your data, it is usually measurably faster to read everything into a VBA array, and loop through that, rather than going back to the worksheet for each item.  In addition, it is generally faster to iterate by index **For I = 1 to n ... Next I** than to go through a **For Each Someobject ... Next Someobject** type of iteration.  So if you did not want to use the above, I would try a code snippet similar to:

```
Dim I As Long
Dim vData As Variant
vData = Union(MyRangeA, MyRangeA.Offset(, 1), MyRangeB)
For I = 1 To UBound(vData)
    If vData(I, 1) = FB And vData(I, 3) = MTH Then
        MyTotal = MyTotal + vData(I, 2)
    End If
Next I
```

Depending on your requirements, you might also, for the latter, consider adding

```
Option Compare Text
```

to the top of your macro.